# Adjacency Matrix vs Incidence Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a simple graph $G=(X,U)$ in relation to the marking $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ of its vertices and $B$ the matrix of incidences of $G$ in relation to the same marking $(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_m)$ of your edges.

How can I show that $A=BB^T-D$ where $D=[d_{ij}]$ is the diagonal matrix, of order $n$ and $d_{ii}=d_G(x_i)$, $ i = 1,\ldots,n$? Does someone have any hint on how can I start the proof?

Comment: What do you mean by "the same marking" of the edges? I don't see how to relate the ordering of the vertices to the ordering of the edges.

Comment: We call the vertex marking of a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices the bijective application $\psi$ of $X$ in ${1, ..., n}$, the adjacency matrix is concerning this marking. To construct the incidence matrix we need to mark the vertices and edges, that is, $(x_1, x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $(u_1, u_2,\ldots, u_m)$ respectively. What I meant was that the vertex marking considered for the construction of the matrices is the same. I don't know if I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_{ij}$ be the entry in row $i$, column $j$ of $B$. $b_{ij}=1$ if $x_i$ is incident to $u_j$, otherwise zero.

The $(i,j)$-entry of $BB^t$ is $\sum_kb_{ik}b_{jk}$.

If $i\ne j$, then this sum is one if $x_i$ and $x_j$ are adjacent (since in that case there's a unique $k$ such that $x_i$ and $x_j$ are incident to $u_k$), and zero otherwise, so it equals the $(i,j)$-entry of $A$.

If $i=j$, so the sum is $\sum_k(b_{ik})^2$, this counts one for each edge incident to $x_i$, that is, it counts the degree of $x_i$, and we're done.